# In randomized block design one way ANOVA, how to proof $SS(Total)=SST+SSB+SSE?$

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, solution-verification, anova

where

$$SS_{\text{total}}=\sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b (x_{ij}-\bar{x})^2$$

$$SST=SS_{\text{treatment}}=b\sum_{j=1}^a (\bar{x_j}-\bar{x})^2$$

$$SSB=SS_{\text{block}}=a\sum_{i=1}^b (\bar{x_i}-\bar{x})^2$$

$$SSE=SS_{\text{error}}=\sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b (x_{ij}-\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j}+\bar{x})^2$$

$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{ab} \sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b x_{ij}$$

$$\bar{x_i}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{j=1}^a x_{ij}$$

$$\bar{x_j}=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{i=1}^b x_{ij}$$

I think it had to start by adding and substarcting terms: $$SS_{\text{total}}=\sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b (x_{ij}-\bar{x_i}+\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j}+\bar{x_j}-\bar{x})^2$$

Then square it to $$\sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b [(x_{ij}-\bar{x_i})^2+(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j})^2+(\bar{x_j}-\bar{x})^2+2(x_{ij}-\bar{x_i})(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j})+2(x_{ij}-\bar{x_i})(\bar{x_j}-\bar{x})+2(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j})(\bar{x_j}-\bar{x})]$$

After that how should I continue?

[RBD references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ0P5.png)

Comment: Is the following re-formulation of your question correct? You have $n\times k$ samples $X_{ij}, 1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le k$. Take the "column-wise means" $$\hat{X}_j=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{ij}$$ "row-wise means" $$\overline{X}_i=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k X_{ij}$$ and the overall mean $$\overline{X}=\frac{1}{nk}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k X_{ij}$$

Comment: Then, $SST$ is defined as $$SST=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k (X_{ij}-\overline{X})^2$$ $SSA$ is defined as $$SSA=n\sum_{j=1}^k(\hat{X}_j-\overline{X})^2$$ $SSB$ is defined as $$SSB=k\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline{X}_i-\overline{X})^2$$ and $SSE$ is defined as $$SSE=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k (X_{ij}-\hat{X}_j-\overline{X}_i+\overline{X})^2$$ Is this correct?

Comment: If yes, can you please either update your question or point to some good reference with those definitions? I have randomly found this page: https://stattrek.com/anova/randomized-block/example.aspx but they call $SSTR$ what you presumably call $SSA$.

Comment: Thank you for your replys, I had reformatting the question, but just the n here is b, k is a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, use instead the notation

$$\overline x_{i\bullet}=\frac1a\sum_{j=1}^a x_{ij}\quad,\quad\overline x_{\bullet j}=\frac1b\sum_{i=1}^b x_{ij}$$
Rewrite $x_{ij}$ as

$$x_{ij}=\overline x+(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)+(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)+(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x_{\bullet j}+\overline x)$$

Square both sides and sum over $i$ and $j$ to get

$$\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}^2=ab\,\overline x^2+a\sum_i(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)^2+b\sum_j(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)^2+\sum_{i,j}(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x_{\bullet j}+\overline x)^2$$

Convince yourself that the product terms vanish.

For instance, $$\sum_{i, j}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)=\sum_{i}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)\sum_j(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)=0$$

because $$\sum_{i}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)=\sum_i\overline x_{i\bullet}-b\overline x=b\overline x-b\overline x=0$$

So,

$$\sum_{i,j}(x_{ij}-\overline x)^2=a\sum_i(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)^2+b\sum_j(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)^2+\sum_{i,j}(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x_{\bullet j}+\overline x)^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are the product terms eliminated before or after the 2 sum? For instance does $$-2\sum\sum \bar{x_i}\bar{x_j}$$ equal to 0? Why?

Comment: They are eliminated after the double sum. For instance, $$\sum_{i, j}(\overline x_{i\cdot}-\overline x)(\overline x_{\cdot j}-\overline x)=\sum_{i}(\overline x_{i\cdot}-\overline x)\sum_j(\overline x_{\cdot j}-\overline x)=0$$ because $$\sum_{i}(\overline x_{i\cdot}-\overline x)=\sum_i\overline x_{i\cdot}-b\overline x=b\overline x-b\overline x=0$$

Comment: One more last question I need to ask, I understand other terms cancelled but only $$\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x})(x_{ij}-\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j}+\bar{x})$$ How to derive it is indeed $0$?

Comment: \begin{align}
\sum_{i,j}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x_{\bullet j}+\overline x)&=\sum_{i,j}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)\left\{(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet})-(\overline x_{\bullet j}-\overline x)\right\}
\\&=\sum_{i,j}(\overline x_{i\bullet}-\overline x)(x_{ij}-\overline x_{i\bullet})
\end{align}
Expand the sum completely. And use $\sum_j x_{ij}=a\overline x_{i\bullet }\,,\,\sum_i \overline x_{i\bullet}=b\overline x\,,\,\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}=ab\,\overline x$.